# when sent via email the <a> tab is unclickable

Tags: html, css, django

```html
<tr style="border: 0 none; border-collapse: separate;">
   <td class="c-rdekwa" style="border: 0 none; border-collapse: separate; vertical-align: 
     middle; padding-top: 38px;" valign="middle"><a href="reset-password.html" target="_blank" style="color: #000000; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; font-family: &quot; HelveticaNeueMedium&quot;,&quot;HelveticaNeue-Medium&quot;,&quot;HelveticaNeueMedium&quot;,&quot;HelveticaNeue&quot;,&quot;HelveticaNeue&quot;,sans-serif;font-weight: 500; font-size: 13.63636px; line-height: 15px; display: inline-block; letter-spacing: .7px; text-decoration: none; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -ms-border-radius: 4px; -o-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; background-color: green; color: #ffffff; padding: 12px 24px;">Recover my password</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

the above code is the area that is of concern. the recover email link is working locally but once it is sent via email it doesn't work in the sense that it doesn't redirect nor take you anywhere its as if it's unclickable

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

this code is what I have at the top
I removed it and used only `<head>` still didn't work

please I need help

Comment: Since you're using Django, perhaps you mean to use `href="{% url 'reset-password' %}"` for your anchor tab?  It looks like you're using an old version of html, are you doing this on purpose?  Finally, it might be better to put all your styles either in an external stylesheet, or within `<style>` tags within the `<head>` section.

Comment: @raphael that is bad advice regarding html emails. Many email clients strip away embedded <style> tags so inline CSS is more widely accessible. However, I do believe the issue is that the OP is hardcoding the link instead of allowing Django to build the URL with the url tag.

Comment: Did not know that, @wjh18.  I learn something new everyday.  Thanks!

Comment: Your email `href` attribute is pointing to a HTML file relative to the current path, which means that email clients are probably stripping it out for security reasons. I don't know Django, but what @raphael says above about the URL makes sense.

Comment: thanks, it's working perfectly.....